# Source code is not foldable in Rmd using a LaTeX "awesomeblock"?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, font-awesome-5, tinytex

I'm working on an R Markdown script with several sections and headers, which I would like to be able to fold while I'm writing the document for better overview.
Usually, it works like a charm, but I inserted an "awesomeblock" using the [awesomebox package](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/graphics/awesomebox/awesomebox.pdf) along with customizations as suggested [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html), and after that, the headers were not recognized as sections in the Rmd document anymore. The rendered pdf looks fine and I can't make out any errors in the rendered tex file.

I noticed that creating a code chunk between the awesomeblock and the section header removes the issue, but that seems very clunky to me. How can I get Rmd to recognize my sections even after an awesomeblock?

```
---
title: "Reprex"
author: "Tave"
date: "2024-03-27"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    extra_dependencies: awesomebox
---

# Some header

## Foldable code, all good

::: {.awesomeblock data-latex="[lightgray]{2pt}{\faLightbulb[regular]}{violet}"}
My really cool box
:::

# Another Header

## Code can't fold?
```

I'm using TinyTex with R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt) on Win 11